# Error preventing from producing bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
structure(list(Young = c(FALSE, TRUE), pop = c(221294L, 574721L), p = c(0.278002298951653, 0.721997701048347)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

I'm looking to make a stacked bar graph using my data frame, however when I use ggplot I continue to get the error.

> Error: stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic.

```
ggplot(data = young, aes(x = Young, y = p)) + geom_bar(position = "fill") + labs(x = "Age Bracket", y = "Proportion")
```

Could anyone explain to me why R won't produce the bar chart, and what corrections I can make to the above code to produce a stacked bar chart using proportions in "p" column?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this might be what you are after

```
ggplot(data = cbind(id = 1,young), aes(x = id, y = p, fill = Young)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "Age Bracket", y = "Proportion")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need `stat="identity"` in `geom_bar`.

```
ggplot(data = young, aes(x = Young, y = p)) + geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") + labs(x = "Age Bracket", y = "Proportion")
```

To get a single stacked bar, define a new variable as shown below.

```
young$state <- c("TrueorFalse","TrueorFalse")

p <- ggplot(data = young, aes(x = state, y = p, fill=Young)) + #
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") + 
  labs(x = "Age Bracket", y = "Proportion")
p
```

[image: output]

Comment: Okay, but how come ggplot is producing two bars as opposed to 2? I'm looking to get the "FALSE" bar stacked on the "TRUE" bar